# Browser Edge adding "?" to datatime chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wcf, microsoft-edge

**Error, removed some not relevant information**

> https://example.com/_vti_bin/myWS/myWS.svc/GetAll/?removed=https://someexample.com&removed2=11&lastModified=?07?/?02?/?2018+?14?:?42?:?24&removed3=0BFBBC8E790D19FB367D50375DFD47CC&_=1518089850935
>
> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider
>   provider)

**Method looks like this - I had to remove some information,**

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Removed")]
    public REMOVED GetAll(string removed, int removed2, string lastModified, string removed3)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime parsedDate;
            try
            {
                parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(lastModified);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lastModified, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
            }
            return REMOVED(removed, removed2, parsedDate, removed3);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrorMessage(ex, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
            throw new SoapException("Unable to get trimmed", SoapException.ServerFaultCode, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Network Tab Parameter value:**

> lastModified:
>   %E2%80%8E07%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E02%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2018+%E2%80%8E14%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E42%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E24

**When debug in developer tools value is this,**

[image]

In code when making a web service call while debugging I can see date and time are in correct format... but when I open network tab and the request made browser EDGE adding unnecessary encoding to parameter. Weird thing is that it works fine in chrome. As a result web services through 400 bad request error for Edge.

Comment: That encoding isn't unnecessary assuming you're making a GET request. There also appears to be no `?` characters in it, as you mention. The decoded string is: `‎07‎/‎02‎/‎2018+‎14‎:‎42‎:‎24` which is entirely valid. What is the actual problem you believe this is causing?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan %-encoding of ascii alpha-numeric characters is *usually* unnecessary... I'd be open to seeing more context, though; if this is a query-string parameter, for example, I might expect `07%2F08%2F2018%2014%3A42%3A24`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Let me add more details to question

Comment: @MarcGravell, Rory Updated my question

Comment: @Mathematics you say the problem is between Edge and Chrome, but you've posted C# server-side code; what is *generating* the url / post / whatever that you're seeing? is it jQuery / DOM? or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell I will add that bit now too, sorry forgot

Comment: Are you using the ´toLocaleTimeString()´ function of Date object?

Comment: @S.Dav yes but code was very tricky to find, I removed it and used moment js library now, thank you everyone for help

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/201